# How to grep logs based on timestamp

Tags: grep

I need logs only from 09:36 to 09:39 in server logs where the timestamp is 2019-03-19T09:37:19 like this. Can anyone suggest me grep  command for this

Comment: you can check the response I left below prior to your issue...

Answer (score 8):

```
grep '2019-03-19T09:3[6-9]' /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you said your timestamp is `2019-03-19T09:37:19`. I suggest you do:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Run the command (`-E` for extended regex):

   ```
   sudo grep -E '2019-03-19T09:3[6-9]' <file or file_path>
   ```

To be direct, the above command could be (if run immediately after <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or another path):

```
sudo grep -E '2019-03-19T09:3[6-9]' /var/log/syslog
```

Or (if in `/log/` folder already...):

```
sudo grep -E '2019-03-19T09:3[6-9]' syslog
```

I hope that's clear enough to help!